# HTTP request takes a long time to execute on Chrome

Tags: performance, google-chrome, http

I've have backend web page that takes a long time to execute but only on Google Chrome. The problem doesn't occur on Internet Explorer, Edge and Firefox.

Below, you'll find the screenshot of my Chrome's Console. On this screenshot, we can see that severals small images take over 14 seconds to load. This happens on local (WAMP) and also happen on an virtual machine (based on an Debian Apache). This is same when browser cache is enable.

[Screenshot Google Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Buo.jpg)

Comment: Take a look in taskmanager from google chrome `more tools -> taskmanager`. Or can you record your request with wireshark?

Comment: When i refresh the page, I can see on the google chroms taskmanager that CPU increase to 115.3 when loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is finally solved. It's a performance problem due to a lot of data loaded in "Datatables" (< 10 000 rows).

The solution is loading data dynamically with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are some plugins for older version that cause problem to Chrome.
This browser isn't able to delete them by itself so you should control if there are old plugins installed on your browser

Comment: Hi, I've already try to start chrome with the --disable-extensions and on 3 differents computers.

Comment: The web page where you send pics are on your pc or in a remote server ?

Comment: My images are on the local directory on the project.